# UWP XAML Windows Phone Dialog issue with soft Keyboard

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I've developed an app, as soon as the user enters a username and password and continues I display a dialog with a selection of buttons for the user to choose. As there is a login screen, the keyboard is displayed. I've hooked into the Enter button so that it is the same as tapping the Sign In button - this is where I hit issues.

IF the dialog is shown whilst the keyboard is active, the dialog content size is not full screen (despite the keyboard disappearing). But if the Sign In button is tapped (i.e. keyboard is not active) everything is fine.

The images below probably explain things better.

[image: Issue example]

I'm not sure what to do to resolve this - any ideas?

FYI - I can scroll the buttons but only in that top section of screen.

Comment: try to make the password textbox lose focus programmatically to force the keyboard to hide.

Answer (score 1):

As always - I ask a question and then find the answer.

When I catch the "Enter button tapped" event, I set focus to the page. It's a bit of a hack as I'd rather know why the issue is happening and stop it altogether instead of just dealing with it, but it works...

```
this.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);// this is the line that solves it.
```

Full code:

```
private void tbPassword_KeyUp(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
    {
        this.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
        StartLogin();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Rick have a good way.But I have other good way that you can make the keyboard show and UWP can arrange the UI.

You can use `InputPane.GetForCurrentView().TryHide()` to hide the keyBoard and use `InputPane.GetForCurrentView().TryShow()` to show the keyBoard. So you can hide it when you want to show the ContentDialog.

But I have not think it is a good way.

You can use `InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Showing` to know when is the keyBoard is Showed and use `InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Hiding` to know when hide the keyBoard .

First,you can make the Grid with a row is show keyBoard when show keyBoard it will get the Hight.

```
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>             
            <RowDefinition x:Name="HightKeyboard" Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

When the keyBoard be showed ,you can use `e.OccludedRect.Height` get the keyBoard's height.

```
        InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Showing += (s, e) =>
        {
            HightKeyboard.Height=new GridLength(e.OccludedRect.Height);
        };
```

And you should make the row height hide when hide the keyBoard.

```
        InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Hiding += (s, e) =>
        {
            HightKeyboard.Height=new GridLength(1);
        };
```

You can show the UI in the first Row ,and when the keyBoard show the height above will be arrange.